# If から can work as an informal emphatic particle, so can ので?

Tags: grammar, usage, sentence-final-particles, particle-から

As many Japanese learners already know, the particle `ので` is mainly used to indicate that the preceding sentence/clause should be understood as a reason that justifies or answers another statement (the best equivalents in meaning in English would probably be *"because"* and *"since"*). So, in this usage, `ので` is perfectly interchangeable with `から`, only differing in politeness level.

However, as I've seen in many sources (like here: [Function of から in this conversation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30999/function-of-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-in-this-conversation/31006#31006)), **`から` can also be used in casual speech as a sentence-ending particle that reinforces what it has been said and gives out an assertive tone** (if I were to choose an equivalent in English for this meaning, I would probably say an *"I tell ya"* tag). So, the thing is, **could `ので` be interchangeable with `から` in this usage too?**

Let me show you an **example of a situation where this may be possible**. This is a troublesome dialogue I found while reading manga: (to put you in context, two waitresses talk about a possible new recruit and a male coworker barges in):

> Adult waitress: 同{どう}級{きゅう}生{せい}入{はい}ったら楽{たの}しいかもよ？
>
> Young waitress: 友{とも}達{だち}作{づく}りで来{き}ている訳{わけ}じゃない**ので**
>
> Young waiter: みてぇなつらら女{おんな} // 誰{だれ}も友{とも}達{だち}になりたかねーよ！

I'm going to write down here my personal interpretation of each line so you could better understand my doubts and why I ended up  making that question about `ので`.

Let's begin: No problems with the first sentence except for that question mark right after the `よ` particle. I would never have expected the `よ` particle to appear in a question given its assertive tone, so I got confused and searched for similar cases. This is the only thing I found: [How do I interpret this question that ends with よ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6524/how-do-i-interpret-this-question-that-ends-with-%E3%82%88). And from what I understood, `よ?` exposes info, but in a *"just so you know"* manner (kinda like a *"keep it in mind"* tag). Consequently, I would translate the adult waitress's line as:

> 同{どう}級{きゅう}生{せい}入{はい}ったら楽{たの}しいかもよ？
>
> *Things might be fun when a classmate joins (to your job), keep it in mind.*

Next is that dreaded line ending in a `ので` that I don't really understand. Following the "normal" use of `ので` (having the same meaning as the conjunction *"because"* in English), the line's translation would be:

> 友{とも}達{だち}作{づく}りで来{き}ている訳{わけ}じゃないので
>
> *Because it's not like I'm coming here to make friends.*

However, that feels out of place to me. If the *"it's not like I come..."* clause should be understood as a reason, which other statement is  being justified/answered? If the young waitress would have said `いいえ` before, or kept on talking, it would all make sense... but the dialogue is just as I wrote, nothing was omitted.

I struggled hard to find a meaning, but I got no satisfactory results. Then I remembered the similitude between `ので` and `から`, and I thought to myself "maybe `ので` works here as an informal emphatic particle like `から`". So I came up with this translation attempt:

> 友{とも}達{だち}作{づく}りで来{き}ている訳{わけ}じゃない**ので**
>
> ***There is no way I'm coming here to make friends, I tell you.***

(Notice that given the hypothetical emphatic tone of `ので` here, I decided to level up the toughness of the `訳じゃない` expression in its translation)

Aaaand finally, the waiter's line. I included this just to show that the young waitress's line has no continuation. But since we're here, I'm going to give it a try anyway (this originally came in two different speech bubbles, hence the slashes):

> みてぇなつらら女{おんな} // 誰{だれ}も友{とも}達{だち}になりたかねーよ！
>
> Look, ice-girl, nobody wants to make friends (with you)!

If anything, I have a minor doubt regarding if he meant *"make friends with the girl"* or *"make friends in general"*. It would be great if you could give me your opinions on this thing too.

And that's all! Sorry for the wall of text. I hope somebody can shed some light on this question!

Answer (score 3):

First, I wouldn’t consider either から or ので emphatic particles. They are 助詞｛じょし｝, or more specifically [[接続助詞]{せつぞくじょし}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E) (conjunctive particles, listed further down the linked page).

ので and から are used identically in the structure you have inquired about. In this construction, rather than ‘because’, think of it as ‘so’.

> ‘I gave up junk food because I’m getting fat.’

versus

> ‘I’m getting fat, so I gave up on junk food.’

As ので is considered more moderate and softer-sounding than から, some modern women prefer to use this word.

> 同級生入ったら楽しいかもよ？
>   It might be fun if a classmate joined the team, huh?

よ？ is used pretty often by relatively younger people when making a statement they feel confident about, yet still looking for confirmation. (若者言葉）. Alternative to ね？ in this case.

You should follow the から or ので to the sentence’s logical conclusion:

> 友達作りで来ている訳じゃないので（、別にどうでもいい）。
>   I didn’t come here to make friends (, so I don’t really care).

The final translation (to me) would sound thus:

> みてぇなつらら女、誰も友達になりたかねーよ！
>   Look here, ice queen. Nobody wants to be your friend anyway!

Comment: そのリンク、接続助詞じゃなくて終助詞のページみたいなんですけど・・

Comment: あぁー、やってもーた！訂正済みです！謝謝～

Comment: ぷかーち、ぷかーち。------

Comment: Ok, first of all, thank you for caring and answering! However, it pains me to say that your reply has left me with even more doubts... You're saying that the second use of から that I exposed is not actually true? Is the answer [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30999/function-of-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-in-this-conversation/31006#31006) wrong? And is my interpretation of the `よ？` ending wrong too? Is the adult waitress not making her statement in a _"just so you know"_ way, but seeking for approval as if she added a _"right?"_ tag? (there's a big difference in nuance there)

Comment: I see the confusion. Your question heading was phrased such that it appeared (to me) that you thought から is an emphatic particle. ので and から can indeed function as emphatic particles, as per your link examples. Those examples, however, still use から to denote an unsaid thought after uttered statement. 「うん、もうすぐ寝るから」 →[うん、もうすぐ寝るから、心配しなくていい）」.

Comment: The  link you included for the explanation for よ？ was quite thorough, I thought. It does have a bit of support. If it makes it easier, just think of adding a question mark as a way of softening the more confident or harsh よ ending.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now! Your answer seems valid and convincing to me, so I don't know why it has 2 downvotes (I upvoted you, though).
 I hope that those who disagree with the explanation above would share their own answer so we could gain more insight into the matter.

Comment: See e.g. http://japan.tsukuba.ac.jp/research/JIAJS8_ON8_Sun.pdf