Ending a sentence with いいから?

先輩の人とはうまくいってるの
それはいいから。。。

A character after a long talk asks her friend "Have things been going on well with that Senpai of yours (as dating)?"
To which the other girl answers それはいいから。。。
There is no more after this sentence as the two characters say goodbye. How is いいから used at the end of a sentence?

This type of いい is not "good" but "unnecessary".

"No, your taste is (not) good"
How to respond to ポイントカードが宜しいですか。
Don't understand the situation in a shin chan comic strip
How to say "no thank you, I don't want / need it"?

So それはいいから means "Come on, let's not talk about that".

In relatively recent English slang (at least some North American dialects), one may say something like "No thanks, I'm good" (i.e. "I don't need [the offered thing]") which seems mechanically rather similar.

@naruto I left my wrong answer as it is for the sake of transparency, but after reading yours, I am left wondering... Okay, いい means unnecessary and therefore, それはいい can be understood as "that's unnecessary". Still I don't think your explanation addresses the original question of "how is いいから used at the end of the sentence?"

@jarmanso, （「～から」がなぜ文末にあるのかをお尋ねでしたら、）その「から」は、終助詞的に使う接続助詞じゃないでしょうか→ https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30999/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58108/9831 また『プログレッシブ和英中辞典』にも例文がありました：から(接続助詞) 〔相手に対する脅し・いたわりなどを示す〕... まあ，いいから，座りなさいよ Oh, don't worry about that. Just sit down.

@chocolate Thank you, that's the point I was (admittedly unsuccessfully) trying to address in my answer. But the links you provided are much better.

If you could provide more dialog or context it would be great, but I'll try to answer anyway.
This から is just the regular から linking cause and effect. Even though the sentence ending is implicit, i.e. it is not said at all, there is an end to the second sentence. Usually, it can be understood from context.
From the question, I can only guess:

先輩の人とはうまくいってるの Is it going well with the senpai(s)?


それ[先輩の人との関係]はいいから[気にしなくてもいいです]。Yeah, that [getting along with senpai(s)] is okay so [no need to worry].


Downvoter, any insights into how can I improve my answer?

^ さあ・・・DVしたの私じゃないんでわかんないですけど、りかいくんは「いいから」自体に "Never mind that" "Don't worry about that" って訳をつけてますね。jarmanso さんの回答だと、「先輩との関係は良いから（＝うまく行っているから）心配するな」と読めてしまうのがマズいんじゃないでしょうか・・？

@chocolate Makes sense, thank you!
